# How to resize a LUKS partition by moving its start?

Tags: partitioning, luks

I have a LUKS partition (sdb2) on a drive which previously contained another Partition (sdb1). Now that I deleted sdb1, I want sdb2 to use this space, too.

All tutorials I could find seem to depend on LVM but I have no LVM setup. Resizing a partition by moving its end sector instead of the start sector also seems easier but this is not the case here.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this without moving the data and creating the partition from scratch?

Comment: I don't know that the tool you are looking for exists.  You'ld need to either dd to a second drive and dd back at the start of your desired partition or copy sector by sector from start old to start new...and if it failed, it would fail badly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safe way:

Back up everything somewhere, then copy data back in the way you want (like the comment suggest).

Tricky way:

[Move your LUKS partition left](https://superuser.com/a/541349/27264), then reisize it "in the correct direction".

Wise way:

Go back in time and set up LVM to avoid such problems.